# MariaDB Galera needs openssl 1.0.0 on RHEL 8

Tags: linux, mariadb, galera

I have a RHEL 8.3 installation.  It comes with openssl.x86_64 1:1.1.1g-11.el8.

However the MariaDB 10.5.7 Galera needs libssl and libcrypto 1.0.0.

```
ldd libgalera_smm.so 
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./libgalera_smm.so'
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd7fbd4000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe012886000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe01267e000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
```

How can I install openssl 1.0.0 without breaking the existing openssl 1.1.1?

TIA

Comment: Download the correct build for your distribution.

Comment: For tarball, I don't see a specific build for RHEL/CentOS here
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.5.7/#bits=64

Comment: Really? I got right to it. Did you click the right options? `For best results with RPM packages, use the Repository Configuration Tool.`

Comment: I know that.  I am looking for a tarball not rpm.

Comment: Stop looking for a tarball and install the RPM.

Comment: I guess it's either that or 1) not using RHEL 8 but RHEL 7; 2) Get Galera separately not using the one from the tarball.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the RPMs for RHEL 8?

Comment: That's a good question.  I always felt more comfortable controlling where my DB installation goes, coming from a Oracle background.  Also, with tarball, I can have multiple versions and use a sym link to switch during upgrades.  More control I guess.  And separation of SA and DBA duties.

Comment: You can always extract the galera shared library out of the RPM using cpio. There are two major versions of galera 3 & 4, so if you have 10.4+ this uses [galera-4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-104/#galera-4)